# Web interface buttons that do mysql inserts and a separate button that does deletes - advice

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, sql-insert

I'm seeking advice for what would be the best way about going about this:

I have an "insert" and a "delete" button that performs queries on a mysql database.

I want to make sure that certain rows with certain keys are not deleted, and also prevent deletion of all rows unless a key is provided.  Basically I just want some advice on the best way of handling deletion to prevent accidental deletion of important data.

There is a mysql --safe-mode but it seems to have been removed in 5.6.  Another option would be to create foreign key constraints to tables containing rows with keys that shouldn't be deleted.

What would be the best way about safely handling this? Maybe some best practices.

Comment: This should be handled in your UI

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you handle all security on the server side. You can do this by introducing an API key on your AJAX calls or with user authentication and roles (specific users only can delete data).

That said, a common "delete" practice is to add a new field to the table(s) that you remove data from. Later you use this to *mark rows as deleted*. This way deleted data remain in the database. An admin UI may allow "undelete".

Similarly, you can introduce new *archive* tables and move there the deleted rows so you can later find them. However, that gets a bit tricky when you have multiple foreign key constraints.